# Cauchy's theorem for existence of solution to nonlinear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I was reading about Cauchy's theorem for existence of solution to nonlinear ODE and the book (Nhan T. Nguyen - Model-Reference Adaptive Control. A Primer) stated "*continuity of f (x, t) in a closed region that contains the initial condition ensures that there exists at least one continuous solution that lies therein.*" As an example the following image is attached,

[image: Nhan T. Nguyen - Model-Reference Adaptive Control. A Primer (2018, Springer) Pg. 38]

But isn't this ODE solvable? It can be separated and integrated to get an answer, even at zero:
$$\frac{x^2}{2}-x= t +c$$

The constant can also be determined by putting Initial Conditions. I would like an example to clarify more on what Cauchy theorem states. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what sense is $x^2-x=t+c$ a solution to the ODE? Note that a solution with the initial condition $x(0)=1$ doesn't exist simply because the function $1/(x-1)$ isn't defined at $0$.

Comment: Also, the text your quoted contains an example - when the initial condition is $x(0)=-1$, Cauchy's theorem applies.

Comment: I can use quadratic formula on $x^2-x=t+c$ to get a solution, $x = 1+ \sqrt{2t}$ (with initial condition imposed). If I put this equation in the ODE then it satisfies it. So how can I say solution does not exist? I am sorry but if I am missing some point here. Please correct me @Micapps

Comment: Well, $x = 1+\sqrt{2t}$ is not differentiable when $t=0$, so it certainly can't be the solution of an initial value problem involving $t=0$. More to the point, again: $f(x) = 1/(x-1)$ isn't defined when $x=1$, so if $x(0)=1$ then $f(x(0))$ isn't defined, and there is no solution to this initial value problem.